# how to override ProfileFormType to edit users? symfony2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, overriding

I'm working with symfony2.I'm using FOSUserBundle, so i want to override FormType of edit user to add name to builder. so how i should do it?

what i've did :

ProfileFormType :

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType as BaseType;

class ProfileFormType extends BaseType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('name')
                ->add('roles', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => 'choice',
                    'options' => array(
                        'choices' => array(
                            'ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin'))))
                ->add('image', new ImageType())

        ;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'user_edit_profile';
    }

}
```

services.yml

```
user.edit.form.type:
    class: UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
    arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: user_edit_profile }
```

edit.html.twig

```
{% extends "UserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}


{% block body %}
    <center> <h1> Modification de profile </h1> </center>
    <aside class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Modification</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Veuillez remplir les champs 
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <!--timeline-->
    <section class="timeline col-sm-9">
        <!--post Timeline-->
        <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-post">
            <!--caption-->
            <div class="caption">


                <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="form-horizontal">


                    <div class="form-group">

                        {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            Name   {{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'form.name'|trans } }) }}
                        </div>

                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">

                        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            Email   {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'form.email'|trans } }) }}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            Pseudo   {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'form.username'|trans } }) }}

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        {{ form_errors(form.current_password) }}
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            Mot de passe actuelle   {{ form_widget(form.current_password, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'form.current_password'|trans } }) }}

                        </div>

                    </div>


                    </br>



                    {{ form_rest(form) }}


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                            <input class="btn btn-default submit" type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> <!--#caption-->


            <!--#post timeline-->
        </div>
        <!--#timeline-->
    </section>





{% endblock %}

{% block js %}

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#roles').hide();
        });


    </script>


{% endblock %}
```

i'm getting this error :

> Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "name()",
>   "getname()"/"isname()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in
>   class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" in
>   FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig at line 28.

How can i resolve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
profile:
        form:
            type: fos_user_profile
```

It needs that at config.yml of fos

Answer (score -1):

Update your service file:

```
user.edit.form.type:
    class: UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
    arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
    decorates: fos_user.profile.form.type
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: user_edit_profile }
```

**fos_user.profile.form.type** is mean our name of service which will be replace our service that name `user.edit.form.type`

Add `use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;`

You got error:

```
Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "name()", "getname()"/"isname()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" in FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig at line 28.
```

due to  fos_user_user table has not name field. If you want to add field whitch not locate in table you'll should add field those fields in entity generate getters and setters and finaly create new migration and migrate up.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I had this error : 

Compile Error: Declaration of UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType::buildForm() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::buildForm(Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)

Comment: @Ld91, make sure you have added `use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;`

Comment: Okay, now i had this error : 

The type name specified for the service "fos_user.profile.form.type" does not match the actual name. Expected "FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType", given "user_edit_profile"

Comment: change user_edit_profile to fos_user_profile in getName and alias service

Comment: The type name specified for the service "fos_user.profile.form.type" does not match the actual name. Expected "FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType", given "fos_user_profile"

Comment: profile:
        form:
            type: fos_user_profile
It needs that in the configuration of fos